# Best way to start posting, for a young person just having a new account?

Tags: discussion

I am young, just started a new account, and looking to begin posting so I can kill some free time. I'm still living like I did in college (posting on various stack exchange site) and I would like to take the extra time and invest it.

What would you suggest are the best options for me to begin? I was considering using [this template](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/best-way-to-start-investing-for-a-young-person-just-starting-their-career) to create some posts, but all the old accounts I used to make similar posts got deleted and I never got any response even after writing a long answer to moderators' private message. I wanted to get the input of the great minds here.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use an existing question as a template and copy text directly from it.

Instead, if you want to learn more about personal finance, spend time reading the content that already exists, both on this site and other sites and books.

Then, if you have a specific question about something you read, post a new question here using your own words. A specific question in your own words will be much better received on this site than the questions you have posted so far.